# How to Add Reference Automatically to a Project when it is in runtime in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, reference, addition

I am new to vb.net. I am creating a program with vb.net. The program has a database. It should have the ability to add an exe file to its database and as reference. When the exe file is added to database it can be run by clicking on an Icon.

I solve the database problem. I can add the exe file to my database and run it. However, the main problem is to add the file to my project references automatically. I mean I want to add the exe file by selecting the file with openfiledialog or something like that. This way, I will be able read some data from the exe file and add them to a database.

For example, My project name is "MY Project". When I run its exe("My Project.exe"), in its menu, I have a button named("Import exe.file"), when I click that button, a window is opened for selecting the exe file.when the file is selected, the program automatically add the exe file to its database and add the file to "My Project" references.
I didn't find any code to add a file to references.
Any help is greatly appreciated,cause I spent more than 2 weeks on this problem, without any progress.

Thanks,
Sepehr

Comment: you cannot add a reference to `exe` file even at design time,so your approach is wrong.

Comment: Since you are accessing the .exe file through openfiledialog you should probably look at the [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Dear Furqan, I can add the exe file to my refrences by rightclicking on the reference and add my exe file. If my approach is worng, could you please tell me how to access the exe file contents inorder to create a database and fill it.

Comment: Dear Tinstaafl, how can I access the file content by "Process Class". I used the process to run the exe file.

Comment: In the process class is an option to redirect the standard input and out of the process before you start it.  This way if needed you can send commands to the process and read it's output.

Comment: Dear Tinstaafl, As I am beginner, I need more explanation. Suppose My application is "a" and exe file is "b". b contains some text boxes and other control types. When "a" is running, I open "b" and fill the text boxes in "b". I want to insert the text boxes value of "b" into a database that is connected to "a". I was wondering if you could give me a sample code or something like that. Thanks